# R data.table multi column coversion by names

Tags: r, type-conversion, data.table, multiple-columns

Let DT be a data.table:

```
DT<-data.table(V1=factor(1:10),
           V2=factor(1:10),
           ...
           V9=factor(1:10),)
```

Is there a better/simpler method to do multicolumn factor conversion like this:

```
DT[,`:=`(
  Vn1=as.numeric(V1),
  Vn2=as.numeric(V2),
  Vn3=as.numeric(V3),
  Vn4=as.numeric(V4),
  Vn5=as.numeric(V5),
  Vn6=as.numeric(V6),
  Vn7=as.numeric(V7),
  Vn8=as.numeric(V8),
  Vn9=as.numeric(V9)
)]
```

Column names are totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the most efficient would be probably to run `set` in a `for` loop

Set the desired columns to modify (you can chose all the names too using `names(DT)` instead)

```
cols <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
```

Then just run the loop

```
for (j in cols) set(DT, i = NULL, j = j, value = as.numeric(DT[[j]]))
```

Or a bit less efficient but more readable way would be just (note the parenthesis around `cols` which evaluating the variable)

```
## if you chose all the names in DT, you don't need to specify the `.SDcols` parameter
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]
```

Both should be efficient even for a big data set. You can read some more about `data.table` basics [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

---

Though **beware** of converting `factor`s to `numeric` classes in such a way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) for more details

Comment: Many thanks, that was it. Especially the second way. I prefer to use names than indexes.

Comment: You can use names in both options, see my edit.